# Mac app float on top of other windows

Tags: macos, window

I'm making a mac app and was wondering how to make it stay on top of all the other apps? Is it something with the `WindowServer`?

Probably totally simple and I'm being an idiot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to play with window layering a bit , you can find more info at ,

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/WinPanel/Concepts/WindowLevel.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000227-136682

Hope this helps